# NestJs:Unit testing how mock function conditional or have many return cases

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

If i going with this approach in case that i want signIn throw exeption with user not found i can't because already findOne mocked with value {_id:'5e81f97e6708f22e5c4697d2', fullName: 'User'} but i want in this case findOne return undefined.
Thank you

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
      const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
          JwtModule.register({
            secret: jwtConfig.secret,
            signOptions: {
              expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn
            }
          })
        ],
        controllers: [AuthController],
        providers: [
          AuthService,
          JwtStrategy,
          {
            provide: JwtStrategy,
            useValue: {
              validate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser())
            }
          },
          {
            provide: getModelToken('Users'),
            useValue: {
              new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
              findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({_id:'5e81f97e6708f22e5c4697d2', fullName: 'User'})
            }
          }
        ],
        exports: []
      }).compile();
      authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController);
      authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
});

it('Should throw exception user not found', async () => {
    const request = {
      email: 'user@gmail.com',
      password: '1234abcd'
    };
    await expect(authController.signIn(request)).rejects.toThrow();
});

 it('Should signIn', async () => {
    await expect(authController.signIn(request)).resolves.toEqual(response);
});
```

Suppose i can in it block mock JwtService sign like this

```
 it('Should signIn', async () => {
    JwtService.prototype.sign = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(accessToken);
    await expect(authController.signIn(request)).resolves.toEqual(response);
});
```

but how do this with injected module getModelToken('Users')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the user model from the module as you already do the controller and authService and provide a new jest mock with either `spyOn` or assigning it a new value?

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
      const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
          JwtModule.register({
            secret: jwtConfig.secret,
            signOptions: {
              expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn
            }
          })
        ],
        controllers: [AuthController],
        providers: [
          AuthService,
          JwtStrategy,
          {
            provide: JwtStrategy,
            useValue: {
              validate: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser())
            }
          },
          {
            provide: getModelToken('Users'),
            useValue: {
              new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
              findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({_id:'5e81f97e6708f22e5c4697d2', fullName: 'User'})
            }
          }
        ],
        exports: []
      }).compile();
      authController = module.get<AuthController>(AuthController);
      authService = module.get<AuthService>(AuthService);
      usersModel = module.get<Model<User>>(getModelToken('Users')
});

it('Should throw exception user not found', async () => {
    const request = {
      email: 'user@gmail.com',
      password: '1234abcd'
    };
    jest.spyOn(usersModel, 'findOne').mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('User not found'));
    await expect(authController.signIn(request)).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i am confused, i dont have Repository if it is mean using typeorm instead i am using mongoose schema if i am not correct please help me how Repository<User> import or do smth i dont know how to use

Comment: Edited for clarity. I made the assumption of TypeORM Repositories instead of Mongoose Models

Comment: Thank you very much, i have confused :) it was very easy with your help!